# How can I set zero price for simple product programmatically?

Tags: magento2.4.2

How can I set zero price for simple product programmatically?

If I set:

```
$product->setPrice(0);
```

In admin panel price field is empty. If I save this product - system return error - price field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to load product by SKU & Factory class:**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productFactory = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::class);

// Load the product by SKU or any other identifier
$sku = 'your_product_sku_here';
$product = $productFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

if ($product) {
    // Set the price to zero
    $product->setPrice(0);

    // Save the product
    $product->save();

    echo "Zero price set for product with SKU: $sku";
} else {
    echo "Product with SKU $sku not found";
}
```

I tried above code & it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP script in the root directory of your Magento installation (e.g., **`set_zero_price.php`**).

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '../../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Load product by SKU
$productSku = 'YOUR_PRODUCT_SKU_HERE';
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku);

if ($product) {
    // Set price to zero
    $product->setPrice(0);
    $product->save();
    echo "Price for product with SKU $productSku set to zero.";
} else {
    echo "Product with SKU $productSku not found.";
}
```

Run the script in the command line or through a browser to execute it:

```
php set_zero_price.php
```

Let me know If any quries.

**`Thanks.`**